# How is this unique lifting a homeomorphism?

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, covering-spaces

I'm self learning Rotman's Algebraic Topology and I've come across this corollary and I don't understand how the author arrived at this conclusion.

What does "the composite and the identity complete the diagram" mean?
And what is "the uniqueness of completion" and how does it show that $hk=1_{\tilde X}$

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have $h: \tilde{Y} \to \tilde{X}$ with $ph =q$, by the (probably previous) theorem. The same theorem with the rôles of $\tilde{X}$ and $\tilde{Y}$ reversed gives us a $k: \tilde{X} \to \tilde{Y}$ with $qk= p$. Both are given to be continuous by the theorem. But then

$$p(hk) = (ph)k = qk = p = p 1_{\tilde{X}}$$ combining the two equations and using transitivity of composition.

So when we apply the same theorem to $\tilde{X}$ and itself, we have two  candidate continuous maps $\phi$ such that $p\phi= p$, namely $\phi = hk$ and $1_{\tilde{X}}$. Both work, as we have seen (so the existence of such a $\phi$ is no issue), and by the *unicity* part of the theorem we have $hk = 1_{\tilde{X}}$, which is half of what we need.

We also have $$q(kh) = (qk)h = ph = q = q1_{\tilde{Y}}$$ and the same theorem for $\tilde{Y}$ (used twice) plus unicity gives us $kh = 1_{\tilde{Y}}$.

So $h$ as $k$ as its continuous inverse and is thus a homeomorphism.

Comment: Ah I see, the uniqueness of "the previous theorem" (The lifting criterion theorem) applied to **second** diagram in the image means that $hk$ MUST equal $1_{\tilde X}$, right?

Comment: @OliverG indeed so t'is.

Answer (score 2):

"Complete the diagram" means the diagram commutes whenever $hk$ and $1_{\tilde X}$ are taken to be the top map. "Uniqueness of the completion" means there is at most one possible top map for which the diagram commutes.
So $hk=1_{\tilde X}$.

Comment: Why must the completion be unique?

Comment: @OliverG "The existence and uniqueness of $h$ are guaranteed by the theorem".

Comment: But "the theorem" (The lifting criterion theorem) only shows that $h$ and $k$ are both unique.  How does their uniqueness imply that $hk$ has to equal $1_{\tilde X}$?

Comment: @OliverG we apply the unicity to the cases where we have twice the same space (see my answer). We only use the existence for the other two cases.